# Parent error when Inserting new page in Gtk.Notebook containing a TreeView widget

Tags: python, widget, gtk3

I did a class that inserts a new tab whenever it is called with a notebook as argument. What I like to do is to associate an appropriate containt to this new tab. I thought that calling my class CreateTab with this widget as argument would be a good idea. But when I make:

```
>>> notebook.insert_page(treeview, hbox, 0)
```

I  keep having this error:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
```

Clearly, what I would like to do is : whenever I click on a button from my main window, for example 'Fish button', it creates a new tab with my widget displaying 'all the fish from the sea'.

Here is my 'CreateTab' class:

```
class CreateTab():
def __init__(self, notebook, title):
    self.notebook = notebook
    self.pages = self.notebook.get_n_pages()
    self.create_tab(title + str(self.pages))
    self.notebook.set_current_page(self.pages)

def create_tab(self, title):
    hbox = Gtk.HBox(False, 0)
    label = Gtk.Label(title)
    hbox.pack_start(label, True, True, 0)
    pixbuf = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default().load_icon(Gtk.STOCK_CLOSE, 16,0)
    image = Gtk.Image()
    image.set_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)
    btn = Gtk.Button()
    btn.set_focus_on_click(False)
    btn.add(image)
    hbox.pack_start(btn, False, False, 0)
    hbox.show_all()
    #widget = Gtk.Label(title)
    widget = Gtk.TreeView()
    widget.show_all()
    self.notebook.insert_page(widget, hbox,self.pages)
    btn.connect('clicked', self.on_closetab_button_clicked, widget)

def on_closetab_button_clicked(self, sender, widget):
    pagenum = self.notebook.page_num(widget)
    self.notebook.remove_page(pagenum)
```

And for instance, the widget I'd like to associate :

class CellRendererTextWindow(Gtk.Window):

```
def __init__(self):
    Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="CellRendererText Example")

    self.set_default_size(200, 200)

    self.liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str, str)
    self.liststore.append(["Fedora", "http://fedoraproject.org/"])
    self.liststore.append(["Slackware", "http://www.slackware.com/"])
    self.liststore.append(["Sidux", "http://sidux.com/"])

    treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=self.liststore)

    renderer_text = Gtk.CellRendererText()
    column_text = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Text", renderer_text, text=0)
    treeview.append_column(column_text)

    renderer_editabletext = Gtk.CellRendererText()
    renderer_editabletext.set_property("editable", True)

    column_editabletext = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Editable Text",
        renderer_editabletext, text=1)
    treeview.append_column(column_editabletext)

    renderer_editabletext.connect("edited", self.text_edited)

    self.add(treeview)

def text_edited(self, widget, path, text):
    self.liststore[path][1] = text
```

I would be gratefull for any help or suggestion since I'm stuck in this for two days !

Comment: You better clarify, when the warnings jumps and what the second code has to do with the first snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to call my class CreateTab with a tab name (str) and a class in argument in charge to create the content.

For example, from main.py, I launch the creation of a new tab called "Supplier's list":

```
CreateTab(title='Suppliers's list', Content=Suppliers)
```

From the class CreateTab, I create a VBox()

```
container = VBox()
```

and I launch Content with the new created VBox in argument.

```
Content(container)
```

So in Content (which can be whatever I want as Suppliers, Customers, Invoices...), I create all my widgets and I attach them in a grid. Here is a simplified Suppliers class:

```
class Suppliers(Gtk.Window):
def __init__(self, container):
    liststore = Gtk.ListStore(int, str, str, str, str, int)
    self.data = session.load_contacts({'type_contact': 'collab'})
    for c in self.data:
        row = ([c.id, c.nom, c.prenom, c.telephone, c.mail, c.actif])
        liststore.append(row)

    # creation of a treeview
    treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=liststore)
    ...

    # creation of a ScrolledWindow to attach the treeview
    scroll = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    scroll.add(treeview)

    # creation of a check button to filter the treeview
    actif_btn = Gtk.CheckButton(label="Active suppliers")
    actif_btn.connect('clicked', self.active_selected, liststore)
    actif_btn.set_active(True)

    # I create a grid to attach every thing        
    grid = Gtk.Grid()
    grid.add(actif_btn)

    # I attach every thing to the initial container
    container.pack_start(grid, False, False,  10)
    container.pack_start(scroll, True, True,  0)
    container.show_all()
```

I hope this will help someone.

I wonder if I can do the same with a window imported from a glade file.